# PHP/SQL deleting an item displayed from a select and join query, without deleting from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT
products.productID, products.name, products.type, products.price, products.image_url
FROM  `products` 
JOIN `orders` ON products.productID = orders.productID
WHERE customerID = '$id'
LIMIT 0 , 30 ";
```

and I looped this through and got a bunch of records. However I have joined two tables and I want to remove the item from the list but not actually delete the item from the table. I am trying to create similar to a shopping cart functionality where you can remove an item without actually deleting the item from the tables. is there any possible way to do it in php? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My old post but a possible solution could be insert the joined result from the query in the question to new table  and reference it with customer ID, that way it is safer or, just use javascript to remove that particular block.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can skip over the records that you don;t want to display before sending the data out to HTML.

In HTML you will need to use JavaScript to remove the items from the list(s).